# do not print if holiday is true - Always tells it is test2

Tags: c#

It is so that I would like to tell the user whether it is test 1 or test 2.

It is depending on whether your Holiday is true or false or that you have not stated it. If you haven't stated it. then it should write test 2 but if it is true in the database then it should write test 1.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ListsignUpInfos)
{
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <p style="margin-bottom:3px;">Firma: @item.Company.Name</p>
            <h4>@item.Title</h4>
            <p>Dato: @item.StartTime.fixDato() - @item.EndTimer.fixDato()</p>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="/User/UserHoliday/@item.Id/@Model.UserId" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-block">
                     @(
                         (item.SignUps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SignUpId == item.Id) != null &&
                          item.SignUps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SignUpId == item.Id && x.UserId == Model.UserId && x.Approve == true).Holiday)
                          ? "Test 1" : "Test 2"
                      )
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">Deltag</a>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**The problem is**: Even though it is true in the database, it will not tell Test1.

How can I get it done so that when it is true it must tell me "Test1" while if there is nothing or look like it must tell "Test2"

EIDT:

I try to : `item.SignUps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SignUpId == item.Id && x.UserId == Model.UserId)?.Holiday == true ? "Test 1" : "Test 2"`

Comment: Why not print out `item.SignUps` to debug?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below

`item.SignUps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SignUpId == item.Id && x.UserId == Model.UserId && x.Approve == true)?.Holiday == true) ? "Test 1" : "Test 2"`

I am using [Null Conditioning Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) to reduce the first null check and explicitly check if the holiday is true.

Link to Minimally verifiable code - https://dotnetfiddle.net/GgZCsF

Comment: This not work. It's the same thing that happens as before.

Comment: @J.Petersen - I tried to place a minimally verifiable code @ https://dotnetfiddle.net/ISHZQs Can you try doing something similar?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GgZCsF <--- Contains all three scenarios. 1. Holiday true in data, holiday false in data and no data

Comment: @J.Petersen - Sorry I could not get you... Is the code still not working?

Comment: Can you paste the complete code just like how you had before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185768/discussion-between-j-petersen-and-ramesh).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
switch (item)
    {
        case 0:
            Test1
            break;
        case 1:
            Test2
    }
```